# SSL has to be enabled to connect to a https site?

Tags: c#, ssl, iis-6, https

I have to send a request as https post to a third party Apache server.

It seems my code is fine as testing to an aspx page shows parameters without any problem, but when I tried to conect to Apache server answers like I didn't send anything.

As I've been digging a bit more, I found out a reference to "servers handshake". Does this mean IIS has to have SSL enabled to conect to the Apache Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.
the ability to call https from your code (hosted on iis) doesn't involves iis ssl settings.
you need to make sure you ignore certificate errors (if there are some) and it should work.